# Test Mail Not Getting Triggered from outbound email

Tags: outbound-email

In our application,we have created Test newsletter mail . In the Outbound email functionality, when i m doing test mail , the mail is not getting triggered up. please let me know how to check this issue.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "not getting triggered up"? It's not clear where in the process the issue occurs.

Comment: Hey swap_Pg, Are you able to see any exception message when you click on "Test Mail". What is the status it is showing once done?

Answer (score 4):

If the Email status is stuck with "Testing Email" check the following

1. First check the Page you have attached in the mail, if you can preview the page. Sometimes due to insertion of outbound Email TBB the page fails to render.
2. Check the configuration in OutboundEmail.xml if the QueueFolder is properly configured.
3. Check the log files, configured in OutboundEmail.xml.

Or if you are getting any error in Tridion notification while testing the mail please mention.

Comment: i have checked the page it preview is fine. we don not have any access to the CMS server. for that particular mail template also mail staticstic is blank.